# Force mobile CSS on desktop

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Is there a way to trick a site to thinking you are accessing it from a mobile device when you are really accessing from a desktop, so it loads the mobile css files?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, under Developer Tools > Settings > Devices, you can set emulated devces

Comment: @Corporalis Some sites have separate css files that load depending on what you are accessing the site from.

Comment: @user4584963 so tell us what is the condition in your case to make mobile css files being loaded. Because, as you've already said, it depends.

Comment: @dragoste I want to visit pinterest on my desktop and make it load the mobile css files instead of the desktop css files

Comment: That's important info. ;-) So, you need a mobile UserAgent header (suggesting youre browser is on e.g.Android or iOS). In Firefox you'll need an addon for that, In Chrome just follow other's advices with developer tools because it's does change UserAgent by default when switching to responsive mode.

Comment: In Firefox, you can simply change the useragent string to whatever you want by setting the **general.useragent.override** setting in about:config.

Comment: I voted to close as this is not about programming

Comment: @LGSon It's about debugging a website.

Comment: @dragoste Thank you!  I had been using chrome devtools by clicking the little phone button, but not refreshing the page.  Thanks for the useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most popular browsers offer built-in user agent switchers, and also you can find extensions

Chrome: Developer Tools --> click the phone icon in the top left corner of the console's window.

IE and Edge: press F12 --> Emulation

Safari: Preferences  --> Advanced --> click the box next to “Show Develop menu in menu bar”. new “Develop” menu will show up select “User Agent”

Firefox: there is an extension called  User Agent Switcher for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to resize the browser.

Or you use chrome, open the developer tools (F12 by Windows OS) and click on the "Toggle Device Toolbar" Icon (Ctrl + Shift + M). In this mode you can choose from different devices like Iphone 5, Iphone 6 etc.

Comment: Some sites have separate css files that load depending on what you are accessing the site from.  For example on SO there is a link that says mobile on the bottom which loads the mobile css files.  Some sites don't have this button so I need a way to force these sites to load their mobile css files instead of their desktop files when accessing the site from my desktop.

Comment: How could resizing browser make to load other css files.